# EXEC sp_spaceused query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have a requirement to scrape 3 million documents. They are all `text` and `varchar` fields. For sample I just scraped 250 documents and when I ran `EXEC sp_spaceused` it gave me 26.6 MB as Database size. I want to know can we calculate the size required to store 3 million documents from this? Offcourse that would be an approximate value. But question is can we really calculate based on this value?

Comment: Basically, yes. Do you have specific concerns?

Comment: @usr: Yes, I would be using VPS hosting for this and the so I need to estimate my requirement.

Comment: If you're using 3rd party hosting, you might consider an alternative approach: storing the documents in the file system, and the *path* in the database. This seems like a *lot* of documents to manage anyway, but I would suspect that the 3rd party host will charge a much higher price per GB on database space than flat file space. You should probably look into that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

250 docs is quite a small sample for 3 million docs. Depending on what else you have in the DB it's hard to say how much of those 26.6 are made up of documents.

I'd say that 26.6MB / 250 * 3000000 ~= 319GB is <del>an upper bound</del> a high estimate on the size of the DB with all the documents, assuming that the 250 you've scraped are representative samples.

Comment: Not an upper bound but an expected value. The real value can be higher or lower.

Comment: I assume that 26.6MB will contain more than just the scraped documents, that's why I wrote "upper bound". If we knew the initial size of the DB *with 0 documents in it* then the *increase* when adding 250 docs would indicate the storage needed.

Comment: That is not an upper bound, it is a systematic positive error. But I see what you mean. +1 from me.

Comment: @usr: You're right I changed to "high estimate". To be an upper bound it has to be sure to never reach it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes you can do this, if you expect the sample to be representative. Can you sample more, like 10x or 100x more?

Anyway, probably you should just consider the size of the tables you created because only that size will increase.

```
Database size = your tables + system objects + unused space (+ log size).
```

You only want to measure "your tables".

If you are on Enterprise edition try turning on compression. It will not work on LOB values though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the log is flushed (e.g. simple recovery model, or DB backed up before the query) you can take this number (which is MB) and multiply it by 12000.

For storing large binary documents and texts, consider using FILESTREAM (SQL Server 2008 onwards).